# Silicone wiper blades for Honda Civic sedan?

Tags: honda, civic, windshield-wipers

I ordered some PIAA silicone blades for my wife's 2006 Honda Civic. They are nominally the right length, but when I put them on they don't lay flat — they curve up so the end is a few inches off the windshield.

I contacted PIAA and they said they don't sell blades for this vehicle, but I would like to know if I can just use a shorter size, use an adapter, or get slide-in silicone replacement blades for the "actual" wiper blades.

**UPDATE:**
I got the non-silicone wipers from the dealer, and they are depicted below. Note there are not metal support brackets like there are with most blades that you can buy. I *think* I would be able to replace the inserts with the appropriately-sized silicone ones from PIAA, but I'm not sure. I'll wait until these wear out to find out. The nominal sizes for these are 575 and 650 mm.

[image: Honda Civic Sedan Wiper Blades]

Comment: I was surprised to find several sites that don't provide wipers for 2006 civic sedans. [wipers123](https://www.wipers123.com/product_display.php?make=Honda&makehid=Honda&year=2006&yearhid=2006&model=Civic&modelhid=Civic) as an example.  I also found it difficult to find the stock wiper sizes for your car.  Do you know what size blades were in it OEM? Which PIAA silicone blades did you buy?

Comment: Thanks @Seminecis. We had to replace the original blades in a snowstorm (when I first discovered the curve-up issue), but I think they were 25 or 26 and 22 or 24 inches.  (Measured a friend's car) I bought 24 and 26 of PIAA but they didn't fit on either side. I am using short ones now that don't bend up, but only clear about 2/3rds of the windshield....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windshield wipers for the 2006 civic sedan don't seem to be available as an aftermarket part.  On [8thcivic.com](http://www.8thcivic.com/forums/mechanical-problems-technical-chat/76396-wiper-blades-what-sizes-civic-si-06-a.html#post7783141) jeff618 says:

> ...
>
> 08-10 Civic SEDAN = 26" DS & 22" PS (more common wiper arm, yet
> different from the coupe arm)
>
> **06-07 Civic SEDAN = Have to go to dealer - aftermarket replacements
> are NOT AVAILABLE**
>
> 02-05 Civics EXCEPT si = 21" DS & 19" PS (fairly standard attachment)
>
> ...

A few options I can think of...

- You would likely need to get new wipers from a Honda dealer in order to fit correctly.
- If you still have the original wipers you could order blade inserts to go in those that are the same size as your originals and they should conform to the right shape being in the original hardware.
- If you still have the originals you might even be able to use the inserts from the PIAA wipers if they are similar enough style.

I hate that stores only sell full wiper replacements now even though all you usually need is the rubber insert.

Comment: Thanks for the research. Yep, I think I will go with a combo of options 1 and 2: get a new dealer assembly and then try to find silicone blades to insert. I will try to refrain from exploring Option 4: get out the pliers and bend the wiper arm until my blades lie flat...

Comment: Laughing at option four but, at the same time, it sounds like something I might resort to.  It might help to heat them at the desired bend so they don't break if you end up with that option ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the only aftermarket blades that will fit on my 2006 Honda Civic Sedan are Rain-X latitude beam blade in sizes B28-2 & B24-2 for the driver and passenger, respectively.  I’ve tried EVERYTHING to avoid buying the Honda 25 cent “$8.95+tax inserts,” and then plus tax for each one every 1.5-2 months.  A few brands DO work, but they are off brands you’ll find at discount stores and hopefully they have two in the sizes you need in an unaltered container.  But basically these Rain-X beam blades fit great, work great, and you can find them on sale at Wal-Mart for $7.88, normally only $9.88 each.  They look good and look oem because of how the clip cover comes down and holds the arm in place.

Comment: Thanks Tom. My wife sold her Civic long ago, but this looks like useful information...